# How to transform a string to a "formula" which allows to use binary operators

Tags: r

I have the following string in R:

```
data<-"-1/(1 - Ft)"  # Ft is a variable provided by the user
```

How can I transform this string in order to be able to operate with it?

This is my desired operation

`data / 5`

which means: `(-1/(1 - Ft))/5`

Do you know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It would be `eval(parse` (assuming  'Ft' is an object created in the global env)

```
Ft <- 4
eval(parse(text = data))/5
#[1] 0.06666667
```